# connect to oracle XE using c# 2010 express

Tags: c#

Just startted with c#. not sure the express version supports connection to oracle or not.
if it does, could anyone let me know the steps to do it?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [ODP .NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) ADO .NET Provider. You can see an example of how to use it [here](http://aspalliance.com/560_Using_Oracle_Data_Provider_for_NET.2).

*Copied from the example*

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;

...

// Create the connection object
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();

// Specify the connect string
// NOTE: Modify User Id, Password, Data Source as per your database set up
con.ConnectionString = "User Id=userid;Password=password;Data Source=dbinstance;";

try
{
  // Open the connection
  con.Open();
  Console.WriteLine("Connection to Oracle database established!");
  Console.WriteLine(" ");
} 
catch (Exception ex)
{
 Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}

string cmdQuery = "SELECT empno, ename FROM emptab";

// Create the OracleCommand object
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(cmdQuery);
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

try
{
  // Execute command, create OracleDataReader object
  OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  while (reader.Read())
  {
    // Output Employee Name and Number
    Console.WriteLine("Employee Number: " + 
                    reader.GetDecimal(0) + 
                                    " , " +
                       "Employee Name : " +


                      reader.GetString(1));
  }
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{
  Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
} 
finally
{
  // Dispose OracleCommand object
  cmd.Dispose();


  // Close and Dispose OracleConnection object
  con.Close();
  con.Dispose(); 
}
```